# not reading the function properly

Tags: r

I think i did not write this code properly since it does not find the proper code inside the function :

```
comp_spread_CDS = function(loss, vec_ZC_prem, vec_ZC_def, vec_prob_suv_prem, vec_prob_surv_def)
  
  {
    nb_payment = lenght(vec__VC_prem)
    nb_step = lengh(vec_ZC_def)
  
    vec_prob_surv_prem_eff = vec_prob_surv_prem + c(1, vec_prob_surv_prem[1 :(nb_payment - 1)])
  
    vec_tenor = rep(tenor, nb_payment)
 
    vec_prob_def = c(1, vec_prob_surv_def[1:(nb_step-1)]) - vec_prob_surv_def
  
    annuity = 0.5 * sum(vec_ZC_prem * vec_prob_surv_prem_eff * vec_tenor)
  
    leg_def = los * sum( vec_ZC_def * vec_prob_def)
  
    spread_CDS = leg_def / annuity
  
    return(spread_CDS)
  }
  
base = 10000
notional = 100
maturity = 5
recovery = 40/100
loss = 1 - recovery

int_rate = 3/100
intensity = 180/base

tenor = 3/12
time_step = 1/360


nb_payment = maturity/ tenor

nb_payment

nb_step = maturity/time_step

nb_step

c(1, vec_prob_surv_prem[1: nb_payment-1])

vec_prob_surv_prem_eff
```

As a result it is telling me that the object is not find by R.

> vec_prob_surv_prem_eff
> Erreur : objet 'vec_prob_surv_prem_eff' introuvable

thank you for your help

sincerely,

Comment: `vec_prob_surv_prem_eff` is an object created within the function. It is not exported when the function is called, and when the function is complete, that object is garbage-collected (removed).

Comment: Your function is using `vec_prob_surv_prem`, which is neither passed to it nor created within the function. That is a bad practice, and will make reproducible use and troubleshooting of this function very difficult. In terms of "*functional* programming", you should always try to write functions that assume nothing exists unless the function creates it (e.g., `nb_payment`) or the object is passed in the function formal arguments. Anything other than that is scope-breach.

Comment: BTW, your function here has other errors, including two typos of the `length(.)` function. I am assuming that since you have not seen that error yet, then one of two things: (1) you haven't called your function `comp_spread_CDS` yet; or (2) this is not a correct copy of your real function.

Comment: @r2evans Isn't `vec_prob_surv_prem` one of the function parameters? Never mind -- it seems to be a typo on OP's part, who has `vec_prob_suv_prem` as a parameter.

Comment: You're right, another typo, good catch. (I just did a browser-page search/highlight-all, and it didn't show.)

Comment: One last point, Unconnuanonyme: you wrote a function, but writing it alone does nothing. If you want its effects, you need to *call* it (and optionally store its return value).